# Android : Apply animation in onClick to all views in a loop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a simple linearlayout with say, 10 Textviews inside it.I want to apply to apply the zoomin animation to textview in onClick.I set the OnclickListener to all the textviews inside a loop and also apply the animation.

**PROBLEM :** when i click on any textview all the previously clicked textviews also zooms in.

layout.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linear">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"/>

    ... 

    ... 

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
List<TextView> txs = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0;i < linear.getChildCount();i++){
    txs.add(linear.getChildAt(i));
}

// OnCLick Listener
public void setListener(){
    for (int i = 0;i < linear.size();i++){
        linear.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.startAnimation(anim_zoomin);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

whats the issue??

Comment: Did the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47459433/6891637) I posted help?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I begin with a view that is completely zoomed out, which means it's scale parameters have been set to zero (programatically in this case).

```
view.setScaleX(0f);
view.setScaleY(0f);
```

To zoom-in, all I would have to do is check the scale parameters of the view and animate the view only if the parameter == 0.

```
if (view.getScaleX() == 0) {
    view.animate().scaleX(1f).setDuration(100L);
    view.animate().scaleY(1f).setDuration(100L);
}
```